# PostgreSQL: Executing dynamic command using EXECUTE .. INTO

Tags: postgresql

I need to create a function which should returns a select statement result from it.

**Example**:

```
Create or replace function fun_test(cola text,colb text,rel text)
returns table(columna text,columnb text)as 
$Body$
Declare
      table_name varchar :='Table_';
      temp_t record;
Begin
      table_name := table_name || rel;
      raise info '%',table_name;

             execute 'select distinct'||quote_ident(cola)||','||quote_ident(colb)|| ' from '||quote_ident(table_name) into temp_t; 

             return query select * from temp_t; /* Error relation "temp_t" does not exist

            /* Here I need to update temp_t also*/

end;
$Body$
language plpgsql;
```

**Error**:

```
ERROR:  relation "temp_t" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from temp_t
                      ^
```

Comment: You can't `SELECT FROM` from a `RECORD` variable. What are you trying to achieve here? You can't do anything after you `RETURN QUERY`, that exits the procedure. None of this makes any sense. Have you read the examples in the documentation?

Comment: @CraigRinger, I need to store the `select` result into table and need to update that table.

Comment: Like we do in normal `select into` statement.

Comment: You can't `SELECT INTO` a table. Are you looking for `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`?

Comment: I want `select numb,rank into temp_t from myview;` to be done there.

Comment: Sorry, this just doesn't make any sense. I think you need to step back and explain the underlying problem you're trying to solve - the "why" for the "how" you're asking here. I cannot figure out what you are attempting to do or why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function might say `RETURNS TABLE(...)`, but it is not constructing a database table for you. "Table" in this context means something entirely different; a better description of the return type would be "record set" (in fact, it's little more than syntactic sugar for `RETURNS SETOF RECORD`).

To build a new database table from a query result, use the [`CREATE TABLE AS`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createtableas.html) statement.

Comment: As a side note, there is a [`SELECT ... INTO <table>`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-selectinto.html) SQL statement which does basically the same thing as `CREATE TABLE AS`, but it is unrelated to the `SELECT ... INTO <variable>` plpgsql statement (and can't even be used in plpgsql, due to the conflicting syntax).

Comment: Exactly! This is what I wanted. Thank you so much.